# BCP command output file directly to cloud storage

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

If I'm using the BCP utility to upload data from SQL Server in Azure to Azure Blob storage, how can I accommodate the Azure storage location path in the code so that the resultant file will be created on the Azure Blob storage location?

For example :-

> bcp mydb..table out <**HOW CAN I PROVIDE AZURE PATH HERE**>\result.txt
>   -c -U userid -S sqlserverinstancename -P password

Answer (score 3):

BCP does not support Azure Blob Storage directly.  You can either copy the files local and then use [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) to move them to blob storage, or, if you are running Linux, you can use [blobfuse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux) to mount a blob storage container in your filesystem and write directly with BCP.

Comment: I hope that this feature gets supported soon, the reason being, in my case, we have an Azure SQL that contains TBs of data that we need to backup to reduce cost, but we don't have a machine that has enough space to persist this as a staging area first, then copy into azure.